# Правописание части «Ново» в топонимах

Tags: орфография, топонимика, слитно-дефис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правила написания названий населенных пунктов с первой частью "Ново". **Ново-Астраханское**, но **Новокузнецкая**.

Answer (score 2):

Для топонимов чёткой регламентации нет.

Полный академический справочник Лопатина :

> Географические названия
>
> § 125. Пишутся слитно:
>
> 1. Названия со вторыми частями -город, -град, -дар, -бург, напр.: Звенигород, Белгород, Ивангород, Калининград, Волгоград, Краснодар,
>      Екатеринбург (но: Китай-город).
> 2. Названия с первыми частями Старо-, Верхне-, Нижне-, Средне-, Ближне-, Дальне-, а также Бело-, Красно-, Черно- и т. п., напр.:
>      Старобельск, Верхнетуринск, Нижнеангарск, Дальнереченск, Белоостров
>      (поселок), Красноуральск, Черноисточинск.
>
> **Примечание**. Первая часть Ново- **может писаться в таких названиях как слитно, так и через дефис**, напр.: Новомосковск, Нововязники, но:
>   Ново-Переделкино, Ново-Косино, Ново-Огарёво
>
> https://info.wikireading.ru/69055

Грамота.ру отвечает:

> Часть ново- в названиях может быть написана и слитно, и через дефис. О
>   принятом написании каждого конкретного названия необходимо узнавать в
>   администрации населенного пункта.
>   http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-

Есть случаи, когда названия улиц и населённых пунктов писались через дефис, а после новых правил 2006 года стали писаться слитно - получилась вообще путаница, теперь нужно иметь в виду дату, когда изменилось название: "Я родилась в Ново-Ивановке в 1938 году, жила где-то, а потом вернулась в Новоивановку в 2013 году". Или писать современное название, а в скобках старое: Новоивановка (Ново-Ивановка).